# Dynamic Inputs In Dash Python

Tags: python, json, input, callback, plotly-dash

This Dash callback reads component ids from a JSON file as the input components. The callback itself works fine when the list is static, but if an id is added to or removed from the list, the app crashes and gives a 'Missing Input Component' error. The JSON file is updating as expected, but the input components are not being redefined in accordance with the JSON changes. How can I fix this?

```py
@dash.callback(
    Output('selectedPatientsStoreBeta1', 'data'),
    [Input(value, 'value') for value in safetyCheckInfoReadout()[1]],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def patientSelection(*args):
    selectionValues = []
    for i in args:
        if str(i) == 'None' or i is None:
            iVal = ''
        else:
            iVal = str(i).translate(str.maketrans('', '', '"\'[]'))
        selectionValues.append(iVal)

    selectedPatients = []
    for index, value in enumerate(safetyCheckInfoReadout()[1]):
        if str(value.split('-')[-1]) in selectionValues[index]:
            selectedPatients.append(str(value.split('-')[-1]))
    if len(selectedPatients) > 0:
        selectedPatients = str(selectedPatients).translate(
            str.maketrans('', '', '"\' []'))
    else:
        selectedPatients = ''

    return selectedPatients
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Using [pattern-matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) could solve this problem. Give your dynamic components dictionary ids:

```py
...
dcc.Input(id={'type': 'my_form_field', index: 1}),
dcc.Input(id={'type': 'my_form_field', index: 2}),
...
```

Handle all their values at once:

```py
from dash import ALL

@dash.callback(
    Output('some_output_component_id', 'data'),
    Input({'type': 'my_form_field', 'index': ALL}, 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def on_my_form_field_change(values: list):
    for value in values:
        ...
```

Not all components support this! For example, `dcc.Input` (from dash core components) does, but `dbc.Input` (from dash bootstrap components) does not.

### Notes

It is also worth noting that passing inputs the way it was shown would not work as desired. Yes, it is possible to bind the decorator's parameters to the callable result. But, in this case, what is passed is the result of list comprehension, which once computed would never be altered anymore. Furthermore, `Dash` actually [parses arguments](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/dev/dash/_callback.py#L276) of `callback` decorator and populates `callback_map` along with some other attributes. So this is not the way to change a callback's signature. To illustrate:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='test0', data='test0'),
    dcc.Store(id='test1', data='test1'),
    dbc.Button('Click!', id='button', n_clicks=0),
    dbc.Input(id='output')])

def get_state(tick: int = 0):
    # switches between test0 and test1
    return State(f'test{tick % 2}', 'data')

# initialize with test1
state = get_state(-1)

@dash.callback(
    Output('output', 'value'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
    state)
def testing(clicks, value):
    global state
    print(f"clicks={clicks}, argument={value}, variable={state.component_id}")
    state = get_state(clicks)
    return value
```

Sample output on clicking:

```
clicks=0, argument=test1, variable=test1
clicks=1, argument=test1, variable=test0
clicks=2, argument=test1, variable=test1
clicks=3, argument=test1, variable=test0
```

The state used stays the same:

```py
print(app.callback_map['output.value'])
# ...
# {
#   "state": [
#    {
#      "id": "test1",
#      "property": "data"
#    }
#  ],
# ...
```