# Plotly Dash State is missing Children items

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a database which the user wants to filter based on dynamic random columns. I have to use those columns as further dropdowns for the column values. The user will select all of them interactively. Hence, I am trying to keep a placeholder in the original app.layout and later generating the Child components. While my dynamic dropdowns are working but I can't seem to call them in my final update of the graph.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Column2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'Column3': [10, 20, 15, 25, 30],
    'Column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
    'Column5': ['A1','A2','A2','A1','A3'],
    'Column6': ['X2','X1','X1','X1','X2'],
    'Column7': ['Y2','Y1','Y2','Y1','Y1'],
})

# App initialization
app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    # Part 1: Dropdown for selecting columns
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='column-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in df.columns],
        multi=True,
        value=[],
    ),

    # Part 2: Placeholder for dynamic dropdowns
    html.Div(id='dynamic-dropdowns-placeholder'),

    # Part 3: Dropdown for x-axis
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='x-axis-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in df.columns],
        multi=False,
        value=None,
    ),

    # Part 4: Dropdown for y-axis
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='y-axis-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in df.columns],
        multi=False,
        value=None,
    ),

    # Part 5: Dropdown for color choice
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='color-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in df.columns],
        multi=False,
        value=None,
    ),

    # Part 6: Dropdown for histfunc
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='histfunc-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Count', 'value': 'count'},
            {'label': 'Average', 'value': 'avg'},
            {'label': 'Minimum', 'value': 'min'},
            {'label': 'Maximum', 'value': 'max'},
        ],
        multi=False,
        value='count',
    ),

    # Part 8: Graph
    dcc.Graph(figure={}, id='histogram'),

])

# Callback to generate dynamic dropdowns based on selected columns
@app.callback(
    Output('dynamic-dropdowns-placeholder', 'children'),
    [Input('column-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def generate_dynamic_dropdowns(selected_columns):
    if not selected_columns:
        return []

    dynamic_dropdowns = []
    for col in selected_columns:
        dynamic_dropdowns.append(
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id=f'{col.lower()}-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': val, 'value': val} for val in df[col].unique()],
                multi=True,
                value=[],
                placeholder=f'Select {col}',
            )
        )

    return dynamic_dropdowns

# Callback to update the graph based on selected values
@app.callback(
    Output('histogram', 'figure'),
    [Input('x-axis-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('y-axis-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('color-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('histfunc-dropdown', 'value')],
    [State(f'{col.lower()}-dropdown', 'value') for col in df.columns]
)
def update_histogram(x_axis, y_axis, color, hist_func, *dynamic_dropdown_values):
    filtered_df = df.copy()

    # Apply filters based on dynamic dropdowns
    for col, values in zip(df.columns, dynamic_dropdown_values):
        filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df[col].isin(values)]

    fig = px.histogram(filtered_df, x=x_axis, y=y_axis, color=color, histfunc=hist_func)

    return fig

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

It returns the following error:

```
A nonexistent object was used in an `State` of a Dash callback. The id of this object is `column1-dropdown` and the property is `value`. The string ids in the current layout are: [column-dropdown, dynamic-dropdowns-placeholder, x-axis-dropdown, y-axis-dropdown, color-dropdown, histfunc-dropdown, histogram]
```

Comment: You need to use [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks).

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: [Dynamic Inputs In Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77491636/21350362)